# How to create private dialogue box using quickblox ios?

Tags: ios, quickblox

I am able to create group dialog box as I found this code:

```
 chatDialog = [[QBChatDialog alloc] initWithDialogID:@"dialogueid" type:QBChatDialogTypeGroup];
chatDialog.name = @" Bob, Sam, Garry";
chatDialog.occupantIDs = @[@(1)];

[QBRequest createDialog:chatDialog successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBChatDialog *createdDialog) {

} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {

}];
```

but when I try to change type to `QBChatDialogTypePrivate`.
Dialog is not creating and can you please tell me what is dialog id and where to find it?

Answer (score 5):

Just init your QBChatDialog with ID nil, server will set it for you and createdDialog that is returned by QBRequest will have correct dialogID.

```
QBChatDialog *chatDialog = [[QBChatDialog alloc] initWithDialogID:nil type:QBChatDialogTypePrivate];
chatDialog.occupantIDs = @[@(opponentID)];

[QBRequest createDialog:chatDialog successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBChatDialog *createdDialog) {

    NSLog(@"Created dialog: %@", createdDialog);
} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {

    NSLog(@"Failed to create dialog with error: %@", response.error);
}];
```

Comment: @MurareePareek Print '[response.error reasons]' in console in order to see what have you done wrong :)

Comment: Thanks Gorbachov. I have an another problem. Iam login successfully but [[serviceManager instance]isAuthorized] always returns false. What is the issue?